# Sharing code between python files

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Lets say I have the following files:

```
-- classes.py
-- main.py
-- commands.py
-- output.py
```

`main.py` is the master file which uses the code from `classes`, `commands`, and `output`. `commands` takes objects defined in `classes` as functional inputs and accesses methods/attributes of these objects. Both `commands` and `classes` use functions defined in `output`.

The question: do I need to import each of these modules in each of the files that depend on them?
i.e.: do I need to import `output` in both `classes`, `commands`, and `main`? Or would the fact that `classes`, `output`, and `commands` are all imported into `main` mean that they don't need to be imported individually?

What is the best practice for handling multiple files with inter-dependencies?

Comment: Best way is to pray a lot, if you're using the Python import system.

Comment: Technically, when you for example `import output` in commands, when you `import commands`, you can access output as `commands.output`... but I wouldn't advise that

Comment: What's the actual concrete thing you're trying to do here? This question is so vague it's unanswerable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The question: do I need to import each of these modules in each of the
>   files that depend on them? i.e.: do I need to import output in both
>   classes, commands, and main?

Yes, this is the way to go.

> Or would the fact that classes, output, and commands are all imported
>   into main mean that they don't need to be imported individually?

No.

Python files are modules. A python module has a symbol table. Every function, class and variable specified in the module are in this table. A module can only use things which are in this table plus Python builtins.

So for example `classes.py`:

```
def function(): pass
class Class(object): pass
```

Has symbol table:

```
{
    'function': function,
    'Class': Class
}
```

You can only use `function` and `Class` within `classes.py` (plus mentioned builtins). You cannot access anything outside of this module implicitly, Python does not have any concept of namespace like C# and Java have. If you need anything from a different file (module), you must explicitly import it.

## Now what really happens when you "import"?

Something quite straightforward - the imported module "becomes" part of the module itself!

In the next example we have `output.py`:

```
def output_function(): pass
```

with symbol table:

```
{
    'output_function': output_function
}
```

and `classes.py`:

```
import output
from output import output_function

def function(): pass
class Class(object): pass
```

with symbol table:

```
{
    'Class': Class,
    'function': function,
    'output': {
        'output_function': output_function
    }
    'output_function': output_function
}
```

where value of 'output' is actually the symbol table of 'output' (the very same object)!

You can even do in a different module:

```
import classes

classes.output.output_function()
```

**But don't**, be explicit about your imports.

It might sound a little bit weird, but this is how Python works. Note there are more things involved, for example when you import a module for the first time it's executed and so on...